# Google site verification of www https site redirected from domain

Tags: google-search-console, apache2, tomcat

I have an Apache Tomcat 8 web app correctly running on my website that is reverse proxied to the Apache2 server which serves up the web app at my domain name. I then provided alias' in my site's conf file in Apache2, and in my DNS Record in my site's DNS Record Management, to redirect http://www.example.com to http://example.com. That all works. I set up Apache 2 to serve the alias www.example.com to domain.com, and have used Let's Encrypt to redirect all http://example.com and http://www.example.com to https://example.com. I encrypted for http://example.com only since encrypting for both domain.com and www.example.com cause my www.example.com browser address to not redirect to example.com (and subsequently to https://example.com). So my browser all works good for either http://example.com or http://www.example.com to redirect to https://example.com. The problem is that in Google Webmaster Tools the site verification for http://www.example.com fails. Says unable to connect to server. Seems the Google verification does not do a redirect. Any insight into this would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please include your redirect code. Otherwise, how would we know?

Comment: I'm able to verify my redirecting properties in Google Search Console.   "Can't connect to the server" sounds like the server went down or is not available.   It doesn't sound like a problem with the redirects to me.

Answer (score 1):

I used the DNS Text Record method for Google site verification. I didn't know the DNS provider so I used Other, making the Text Record at A2 Hosting, and waiting for the DNS changes to propagate. All works now. Thanks for the replies.

Answer (score 0):

From your site admin, go to Navigation.
Click URL Redirects:
Click Add URL redirect:
Enter the old URL you want to redirect visitors from in the Old URL field. Only broken URLs should be redirected. ...